# Kendo UI Grid - Where to look for fonts and icons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm in the early stages of learning Kendo UI. I've got the grid work and loading data but none of the images/icons that should appear in the grid are appearing. When I load the page containing the grid, I get the following 404 errors. The error message doesn't tell me where it's expecting to find these files.

Where is Kendo UI looking for these files? Or, can I tell Kendo where to look for them?

[image]

I currently have the files located here in my MVC folder structure, but it's not finding them:

[image]

Comment: Resolved here for me: https://www.telerik.com/forums/font-bundles-and-404-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fonts and icons should be located under the `content\kendo\{your kendo version}\` (assuming you are creating an MVC.net site based on the tag (see image below)

if this is missing then try running the upgrade wizard in visual studio (assuming you are using visual studio here) or just include the files you require from your distribution.

can you also check you have included the required css links within your site (please note I am using the bootstrap theme here so alter to work with your theme as required):

```
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.118/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.118/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.118/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.118/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.118/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

if this is set up correctly just make sure the fonts etc are set to "content" for the 'Build Action'

[image: Example image of kendo content layout]

Comment: they should be located under the content folder at the root of the application/website. If they are not on your `published` website then you may have exlcuded them from the deploy.

Comment: I've updated my post to show where they are currently located. But I still get 404 errors and the version of Kendo is correct.

Comment: have you included the required css initialisation within your site. I have updated my answer to include this for you

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have all the .css files loading correctly because the grid appears to render correctly in every respect except for the various icons and images, such as on the navigation bar and 'Add New Record' button etc.

Comment: I am just trying to eliminate potential issues here. In that case then have you checked to see if you can navigate to the files manually i.e. {your site}/content/kendo/2017.1.118/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf if it is found then it should try to download the file. If not then it means the build action for the file is wrong and that can be changed by simply clicking the file going to the properties screen and change `build action` to `Content` and then this should get included.

Comment: Thank you. You've been a big help. I haven't figured this out yet, but you've got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the version in your direction matches the version of the kendo.mvc.dll in your bin folder.  It has to match your assembly version.

I found this out when I upgraded. Somehow my project was not pointing to the correct assembly.