# Kendo Combobox icons are not loading

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, nopcommerce, kendo-combobox

This is the content of the "Content" folder, as mentioned here in the official docs: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling

[image: t l]

Added the required CSS and JS file :

[image]

The Kendo Combo-box functionality is working fine(except the icons):

[image]

I have also followed these answers on stackoverflow:

[Icons not showing in my KendoUI for JQuery Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186657/icons-not-showing-in-my-kendoui-for-jquery-grid)

[Kendo UI Grid - Where to look for fonts and icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273892/kendo-ui-grid-where-to-look-for-fonts-and-icons)

In the network tab of chrome developer tools, I don't see the WebComponentsIcons file loaded:

[image]

Let me know what is the step that I am missing?

UPDATE:

I have added the missing fonts, textures, and Default folder in kendo folder, but still, the icons are not showing up:

[image]

any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of Kendo are you using? Are you using less- or sass-based themes?

Comment: Kendo version: 2020.2.513.

For the default theme, I used this CSS file: kendo.default.min.css. But I am not sure about the type(less/sass).

Comment: any suggestion on how could I proceed?

Comment: I have cross-checked it, and as I have followed this link for setting up it is a less-based theme: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling